# How to display spesific category on search result

Tags: php, html, wordpress, search

How can I display search results in a specific category? e.g When searching for word 'articles', search results should display category 'Articles'.

Comment: You want to change the default WP search, so it searches categories, not posts? Or you want to implement a search, that searches categories?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to create this feature with the `post_search` wordpress filter.

See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_search

The `post_search` filter  is executed before the category check so you should be able to set the category in the query based on the search terms. Beyond that it is a matter of adjusting your template(s) to display the category used by the query.